# java8 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException during forEach cycle

Tags: java, lambda, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I use java8 streams. Here is the data structure I have:

```
Map< String, List< String >> mmessage = getSomeMessage();
```

Then I iterate via the map and list:

```
 mmessage.entrySet().stream().forEach( entry -> {
            entry.getValue().stream().forEach( li -> {
                if ( lis.indexOf( li ) == - 1 )  {
                    lis.add( lineItem );
                }
            });
        });
```

But get concurrent modification exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at com.web3.buyer.roomba.RoombaTurn.lambda$received$3(RoombaTurn.java:296)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at com.web3.buyer.roomba.RoombaTurn.received(RoombaTurn.java:295)
    at com.web3.buyer.SystemBus.lambda$publishToTheQueue$0(SystemBus.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From my understanding iterating via the map \ list should not cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: What is `lis` and how is it related to the `mmessage` `Map`?

Comment: You can not add valies to the list you are iterating over

Comment: @Jens OP is not adding values to the same list (at least we don't know that yet, since we don't know what is `lis`).

Comment: yes, i understand this, lis it is just another structure, like lis = new ArrayList< String>(); but you right it fails on it on different reason. Thanks!

Comment: `lis` is a value in the map; this is why it fails.

Comment: his code will not give any exception if lis is separate list. I tried it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would write this using a full functional style and you shouldn't run into the problem of modifying a list while iterating it.

```
List<String> strs = mmessage.values().stream()
                            .flatMap(List::stream)
                            .distinct()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```